# How to filter dataframe for column with lists contains value

Tags: python, list, pandas, filter

We have dataframe with lists in one column. Couldn't find easy way to filter dataframe for rows contains value in their lists.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lists':[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c', 'd']]})
```

For example I need only rows contains 'a' in their lists.
I managed to get it only through 'apply'.

```
df[df.lists.apply(lambda x: True if 'a' in x else False)]
>>>     lists
>>>0    [a, c]
>>>1    [a, b, d]
```

Is there is anything like .isin(), but vice-versa?
What is the best way to get needed rows?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simpliest is use `apply` with `in`:

```
df1 = df[df.lists.apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
```

But if want check `a` create `DataFrame`, but it is a bit complicated:

```
df1 = df[pd.DataFrame(df.lists.values.tolist()).eq('a').any(axis=1)]
```

Another solution is use [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1 = df[df.lists.str.join(',').str.contains('a')]
```

---

```
print (df1)
       lists
0     [a, c]
1  [a, b, d]
```

Comment: what about if I need to check if df contains particular list of values? , like [a,b,d] f.e.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean indexing via a list comprehension is one way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lists':[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c', 'd']]})

df[['a' in x for x in df['lists'].values]]

#        lists
# 0     [a, c]
# 1  [a, b, d]
```

Some performance benchmarking:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lists':[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c', 'd']]})

df = pd.concat([df]*100000)

def jez1(df):
    return df[df.lists.apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]

def jez2(df):
    return df[pd.DataFrame(df.lists.values.tolist()).eq('a').any(axis=1)]

def jez3(df):
    return df[df.lists.str.join(',').str.contains('a')]

def jp(df):
    return df[['a' in x for x in df['lists'].values]]

%timeit jez1(df)  # 87ms
%timeit jez2(df)  # 122ms
%timeit jez3(df)  # 416ms
%timeit jp(df)    # 53ms
```

Comment: Nice job. Thank you!